# Laravel 5.0 Scheduling Commands (Possibly with queues)

Tags: php, laravel, cron, command, queue

I'm having a bit of trouble grasping the concept of Queues in laravel 5.0. From what I understand, queues store a list of Commands to be executed by either by the `php artisan queue:listen` command or the `php artisan queue:work --daemon` command.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `php artisan queue:listen` just waits until there is a command in queue and then executes it, right? Then what does the `php artisan queue:work --daemon` command do in comparison? Does this command only work one at a time?

Anyways, a task I wish to complete is this... I want to periodically check if there are commands in the queue and if there are I wish to execute them. Since this is a periodic problem I assume a chron would be used, but how do i check if there are outstanding commands to be? Would I run a query on my queue table? If I do, how would I dispatch the command? Or should I just chron the `php artisan queue:listen` command

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between queue:listen and queue:work is that the second one only sees if there's a job waiting, takes it and handles it. That's it.

The listener though runs as a background process checking for jobs available all the time. If there's a new job it is then handled (the process is slightly more difficult, but that's the main idea).

So basically if you need to handle your commands (jobs) as soon as they appear you might wanna use the queues.

And if you need to do something periodically (for example every 2 hours or every Monday at 9 AM etc.) you should go with cron + Schedule.

I wouldn't recommend combining them as you described. Also keep in mind that jobs can be delayed if you don't want then do be handled ASAP.